# jQuery .get() function returns an error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery code:

```
$("#delete_products").click(function() {
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        var pid = $(this).val();
        $.get('delete_product.php',{pid: pid});
});
location.reload();
});
```

for some reason, the `$.get()` function doesn't work. when I run the `.fail()`, it does tell me that it has failed.

Here is my delete_product.php page:

```
if(isset($_GET['pid']) && !empty($_GET['pid']) && is_numeric($_GET['pid'])){
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `id` = $pid LIMIT 1";
    $query_run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $query = "DELETE FROM `products2categories` WHERE `product_id` = $pid";
    $query_run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $pictodelete = ("../products_images/$pid.jpg");
    if(file_exists($pictodelete)){
        unlink($pictodelete);   
    }
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Check the console for an error message, if you find one please add the details to your question.

Comment: And check the server log.

Comment: I'm sorry but no error message has been produced in the console

Comment: Sorry? I'm running it all on a localhost. What do you mean by "200 code"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're calling `location.reload` before the request is finished. This cancels the requests if they haven't already been returned. If you want the page to reload afterwards, try this:

```
$("#delete_products").click(function () {
    var promises = [];
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        var pid = $(this).val();
        promises.push($.get('delete_product.php', {
            pid: pid
        }));
    });
    $.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
        location.reload();
    });
    return false;
});
```

For more information about what exactly is happening, take a look at jQuery documentation about `$.Deferred`: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: This solution didn't work :/ the items are still not being deleted. Maybe there is a way to actually show the error message then I can post it here?

Comment: Try commenting out the `location.reload` and on each `.get` add a `.fail` function to get the error message and let us know. Also, check the Network tab (in chrome) and see what is happening when it calls the get.

Comment: When I comment out the location.reload, it works just fine!
any idea how can I force the page to refresh after deleting?

Comment: Try something like this (replacing the get with yours): http://jsfiddle.net/gBmPZ/ In the console you should see them all in order. Then try this one – http://jsfiddle.net/gBmPZ/1/ – if the first doesn't work and see if the `setTimeout` fixes the issue.

Comment: The only suggestion I have is: in your PHP page, [check if it's a ajax call](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax), and if it is, echo a value (`success`, for example), and if it's not, do the `header("location: index.php")`

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
   $query = "DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `id` = $pid LIMIT 1";
```

I think should be:

```
   $query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE `id` = $pid LIMIT 1";
```

Use the `` char only for field name not for table name. I use firebug and always get a "500 Internal server error" in cases like this